# How to I query for the inherited class type in Java/MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Item is an abstract class, which is implemented by both the Material and Product classes.

The Distribution entity has an attribute "item" which is of an Item type. How do I check if the "item" is of the Product type? Right now I'm using this but it doesn't seem to be optimal.

```
"SELECT d FROM " + Distribution.class.getName() + " d, " + Product.class.getName() + " p WHERE d.item = p"
```

Comment: With `instanceof`, but if you need to do this you're already doing something else wrong.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Product.class.getName()` will return the fully qualified class name.

However, if you have something like :

```
Item item1= new Product();          Then 
item1.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

will return **Product** as a String type.

So you can have :

```
if(item1.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Product")) {
    // Do something like 
    Product product = (Product)item1;
```

Comment: Thanks, can I do this in the query itself?

Comment: @octopish, The more important question is that aren't you saving all the data related to the Product and Materials class in same table ?

Comment: @octopish, Then how can you be so sure of whether the item being retrieved is of type Product Or Materials. Definitely you cannot be. Moreover, query is meant to be written in plain language and when the Object is retrieved from the database table then you can use the above code to verify , whether it belongs to Product or Material.

Comment: I realise that I can't be sure of whether the type is Product or Material, thus my question was if there actually exists a way to query the Item type inside the SQL query

Comment: @octopish With plain JDBC code, them I'm not aware of any such way. However, this can be easily done with Hibernate.

Comment: @octopish Look There is a significant diffrence b/w the Object model which Java follows and the Relational Model which any RDBMS follows. so ther is no direct way to map the diff b/w the two. And this is where ORM tools like Hibernate makes life easier. If you are satisfied with the answer then mark it as accepted Or else if you have something else then Ask it as another question. Happy coding !